# arguments in functions python

Tags: python, arguments

This is a subtle question about notation. 
I want to call a function with specific arguments, but without having to redefine it.

For example, `min()` with a key function on the second argument `key = itemgetter(1)` would look like:

```
min_arg2 = lambda p,q = min(p,q, key = itemgetter(1))
```

I'm hoping to just call it as something like `min( *itemgetter(1) )`...

Does anyone know how to do this?  Thank you.

Comment: "but without having to redefine it."  How can this possibly be avoided?  What are you trying to do?  If `min()` doesn't mean `__builtins__.min()` people will hate you.

Answer (score 10):

You want to use `functools.partial()`:

```
min_arg2 = functools.partial(min, key=itemgetter(1))
```

See http://docs.python.org/library/functools.html for the docs.

Example:

```
>>> import functools
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> min_arg2 = functools.partial(min, key=itemgetter(1))
>>> min_arg2(vals)
('b', 0)
```

Comment: Where do you define vals?

Answer (score 2):

Using functools (as in [Duncan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7532583/arguments-in-functions-python/7532627#7532627)) is a better approach, however you *can* use a [lambda expression](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-forms), you just didn't get the syntax correct:

```
min_arg2 = lambda p,q: min(p,q, key=itemgetter(1))
```

Comment: thanks, that mistake wasa typo, although functools.partial was what I wanted.